# How to improve MySQL DELETE query performance

Tags: mysql, performance

Using: MySQL 5.6 on Windows, with default configuration file settings in my.ini

Table: datatbl1

```
row_id   | emailaddr    | valid
--------------------------------  
INT, PK  | VARCHAR(255) | BIT
```

Both emailaddr and row_id columns each have an index defined.

There are 600,000 rows in the table, and the objective is to remove duplicates. The query is:

```
delete dt2 from datatbl1 dt1 JOIN datatbl1 dt2 on (dt1.emailaddr = dt2.emailaddr) and (dt1.row_id < dt2.row_id);
```

On my system, it takes about 15 minutes to complete this query, I watch the mysqld process in the Task Manager, processor usage is 100% the whole time, but memory usage never crosses about 140MB, even though there is about 3GB of memory (RAM) installed and plenty memory available.

Questions:

1. Can I change some configuration parameters to increase the performance?
2. Can the query itself be rewritten to increase performance?
3. Whats a reasonable amount of time to execute this query with say 1 - 2 million rows?

Keep in mind that this query later needs to be applied to other tables, ie delete matches in datatbl1 for records that match other tables (datatbl2, datatbl3, datatbl4 etc) which have the same table structure.

On my client's system, the same query is taking 2 hours. Difference is that he has a normal hard drive, whereas I have a SSD.

The application is a client server application with a Delphi front-end, and is meant to be used by ordinary users on Windows PCs, thus MySQL will be almost always be running on a end-user Windows PC.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
The Explain output as requested is:

```
mysql> explain delete dt2 from datatbl1 dt1 JOIN datatbl1 dt2 on (dt1.emailaddr
= dt2.emailaddr) and (dt1.row_id < dt2.row_id);
+----+-------------+-------+-------+------------------------------+-------------
+---------+--------------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys                | key
| key_len | ref                      | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+------------------------------+-------------
+---------+--------------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | dt1   | index | PRIMARY,ixemailaddr,ixrow_id | ixemailaddr
| 257     | NULL                     |    1 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | dt2   | ref   | PRIMARY,ixemailaddr,ixrow_id | ixemailaddr
| 257     | emailmgrdb.dt1.emailaddr |    1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+------------------------------+-------------
+---------+--------------------------+------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Is this a one off event due to you not using the `UNIQUE` keyword?

Comment: Can you post a `EXPLAIN` result of your query?

Comment: @piotrekkr : Explain result posted.

Comment: @SteveF - The question is are you going to use `UNIQUE` in the future to avoid this problem hence just only having to do this once?

Comment: @EdHeal: The answer is no. UNIQUE will not be used in future.

Comment: @SteveF - IMHO I think you ought to redesign the database so it uses 3NF

Comment: @EdHeal: The whole app is based around 5 tables that are exactly the same structure. The user is a bulk email marketer and only needs to maintain a list of email addresses, and is importing about 100,000 new email addresses into the database daily. He currently maintains the list in Excel, and to remove duplicates he does it in about 30 seconds with a VLOOKUP function. So how exactly will 3NF help in this case?

Comment: @SteveF - You maintain the database so that a table has no duplicate rows so you would not be in this mess in the first place. If you are importing them am had the unique constraint (say on email address) the database will not add an extra row. It is worthwhile learning about it for good database design (btw 3NF - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form

Comment: @EdHeal: Well my app has a different requirement than that. There are other tables that contain email addresses (datatbl2, datatbl3, datatbl4, datatbl5). After every import into any of these tables, we need to run a query to remove the matching email addresses from datatbl1. So even if there are no duplicates in datatbl1, we still need to run the same query against the other tables to find & delete matches.

Comment: @stevef - If you set up the database in 3NF then the import will work as you require without the need to run another query after the import. The database will handle the business logic and keep itself with the required constraints being observed. Guess you do not understand 3NF.

Comment: No sure I understood how to apply what you describe to my app, but hey the main problem I posted about has been solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this query will be faster:

```
DELETE dt1.*
FROM datatbl1 dt1
JOIN (SELECT emailaddr, MIN(row_id) minrow
      FROM datatbl1
      GROUP BY emailaddr) dt2
USING (emailaddr)
WHERE dt1.row_id > dt2.minrow
```

The size of the intermediate table in your original query is O(n^2) (because it joins each row with all the duplicates that follow it), but this one is O(n) (because it only joins the first row of each set of duplicates with the ones that follow it).

It depends on whether the slowness is in finding the rows or performing all the deletions. You can find this out by doing SELECT instead of DELETE and noting the performance difference.

Comment: It works really well. The query now completes in 4 secs and produces the correct result. Outstanding!

Comment: Question - Will removing the index on row_id have a negative impact difference? It is already a PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: In a similar light, and in the same database, is there a way to improve this query: "update datatbl1 dt1 join datatbl2 dt2 on  
  (dt1.emailaddr = dt2.emailaddr) set valid = 0;"

Comment: A primary key is automatically indexed, so there's no need to have a separate index for it. I think that update query should work well as long as both tables have indexes on emailaddr.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving the `row_id` comparison to the `WHERE` clause?

```
DELETE dt1
FROM datatbl1 dt1
INNER JOIN datatbl1 dt2 ON dt1.emailaddr = dt2.emailaddr
WHERE dt1.row_id > dt2.row_id
```